# Refreshing second System.Windows.Forms.Form

Tags: powershell, winforms

I'm having a problem with forms in PowerShell and not sure if it's my code or its forms can't do it.

below is a sample of what I'm trying to do. I have a button on the "form1" that opens a new form "form2". I set it up so I'm not locked into form2 and can still click on the button in form1. when I click the button again, I want it to update the current form2 window with the new texted but instead it opens a new window.

```
$Form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form1.Text = "Form 1"

$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Text = "Edit"
$button.Add_Click({
        if ($Form2.IsHandleCreated) {
            $Form2.Invalidate()
            $Label.Text = "Clicked Again"
        }
        else {
            $Form2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
            $Form2.Text = "Form 2"
            $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

            $Label.Text = "First Click"
            $Form2.Controls.Add($Label)
            $Form2.Show()
        }
    })
$Form1.Controls.Add($button)
$Form1.ShowDialog()
```

I know it's something to do with "if ($Form2.IsHandleCreated)" when I try debugging it, it looks like it's not seeing the current form2 is not open I just not sure how to get it to see it.

---

Tried this and still getting the same thing.

```
$Form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form1.Text = "Form 1"

$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Text = "Edit"
$button_Click= {
    if ($Form2.IsHandleCreated) {
        $Form2.Invalidate()
        $Label.Text = "Clicked Again"
    }
    else {
        $Form2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $Form2.Text = "Form 2"
        $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

        $Label.Text = "First Click"
        $Form2.Controls.Add($Label)
        $Form2.Show()
    }
}
$button.Add_Click($button_Click)
$Form1.Controls.Add($button)
$Form1.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Typo?  `$From2` != `$Form2`

Comment: sorry about that forgot to update that, even with the correction it's still not working (updated code)

Comment: Your `$Form2` variable is scoped to the `add_Click` handler, it'll stop existing as soon as the button has been clicked.

Comment: so I updated the code and put it in a variable first, but still getting the same thing. every time I click the button it runs the else statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the types in the script's scope, both Form and Label, then create the objects in the Button's `Click` handler.
If you declare the types in the handler's scope, their Handles are never seen as created, since the objects' life is restricted to that context, so `$Form2.IsHandleCreated` is never true and a new window is created each time (and the windows previously created are *orphaned*).

If `$Form2` is created, you also need to explicitly close it (dispose of it) when `$Form1` closes, otherwise `Form2` will, again, become *orphaned* when the script terminates (hence, it's most probably going to get *stuck*, given that you presented it with `Show()` and not `ShowDialog()`, so when the starting Form closes, there's no [message loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues) anymore).
You can do that after `$Form1.ShowDialog()` returns, or in the `FormClosed` event handler of `$Form1`.

`[$Form].Invalidate()` is not really useful here, replace it with `.BringToFront()` if you want to make Form2 the current foreground window (calls `SetWindowPos()` + `HWND_TOP` under the hood)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form1 = [System.Windows.Forms.Form] @{
    StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
    Text = "Form 1"
}

[System.Windows.Forms.Form]$Form2 = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.Label]$Label = $null

$button = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Text = "Edit" }
$button.Add_Click({
        if ($Form2.IsHandleCreated) {
            $Label.Text = "Clicked Again"
            $Form2.BringToFront() # If it needs to be the active foreground window
        }
        else {
            # Create the objects declared at script scope
            $script:Form2 = [System.Windows.Forms.Form] @{ Text = "Form 2" }
            $script:Label = [System.Windows.Forms.Label] @{ Text = "First Click" }
            $Form2.Controls.Add($Label)
            $Form2.Show()
        }
    })
$Form1.Controls.Add($button)
$Form1.add_Shown({$Form1.Activate()})
$null = $Form1.ShowDialog()

if ($Form2.IsHandleCreated){ $Form2.Dispose() }
# Or...
#if ($Form2 -ne $null){ $Form2.Dispose() }
```